# Android SDK Manager download unnecessary packages during build, lint or assemble apk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-manager

I was playing with setting up the Android SDK and found that the Gradle plugin was downloading extra packages when building: like build tools (understandable) and emulator (not needed). The problem came up with creating a docker image for building projects on Android, and my goal was to have the smallest build tool possible. Is there a way to prevent unnecessary packages from being downloaded?